# Access to X server denied from command line

Tags: command-line, server

I just installed Ubuntu 15.04  and the Gnome 3 desktop environment.
If I try to run a GUI program from the command line (like Gedit), I get:

```
XXXXX:~$ gedit 
No protocol specified

** (gedit:3299): WARNING **: Could not open X display
No protocol specified
gdk_mir_display_open
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:3299): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0

But, if I launch gedit from the  gnome "search" window, it comes up fine.
I have some custom GUIs I use and I typically start them from the command line.
```

p.s.  I cannot use the Ubuntu desktop env. b/c of problems with Nvidia HW.

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `echo $DISPLAY`